# Docker BuildKit not Parallelizing Independent Stages without `echo`s

Tags: docker, parallel-processing, cpu-usage, docker-build, docker-buildkit

Assume `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`.

Take `main.py`:

```
i = 0

while True:
    i += 1
```

Take this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as base
COPY main.py .

FROM base as part_1
RUN echo "A" && python -m main

FROM base as part_2
RUN echo "B" && python -m main

FROM base as combined
COPY --from=part_1 . .
COPY --from=part_2 . .
```

Running `docker build --no-cache .` followed by `top` shows that the build is being parallelized to take 2 cores, [expected from BuildKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61957620/5319267):

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND              
  22569 root      20   0   14032  11620   4948 R 100.0   0.0   0:10.43 python               
  22571 root      20   0   14032  11620   4948 R 100.0   0.0   0:10.34 python
```

But removing the `echo`s from the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as base
COPY main.py .

FROM base as part_1
RUN python -m main

FROM base as part_2
RUN python -m main

FROM base as combined
COPY --from=part_1 . .
COPY --from=part_2 . .
```

and rerunning `docker build --no-cache .` followed by `top` shows that the build is only taking one core (with the second process being an irrelevant one), unexpected from BuildKit:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
  24674 root      20   0   14032  11624   4952 R 100.0   0.0   1:00.40 python   
   2485 mishac    20   0 5824548 515428 126120 S  12.3   1.6   2:52.74 gnome-s+
```

Why is the version without the `echo`s disabling the parallelization? It seems like an odd thing to be affecting it. Is it possible to keep the parallelization without the `echo`s?

Version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buildkit uses a **low-level builder** format (LLB) to compute a [content addressable dependency graph](https://blog.mobyproject.org/introducing-buildkit-17e056cc5317). This allows it to optimize the build process by **directly tracking the checksums of build graphs**. All stages are analyzed before any processing is done.

Since you are starting from the same the same base image and executing the same `RUN` command in each stage, Buildkit determines that this will produce the same output and only performs this operation once.

When you add the `echo` command, you introduce a variance in the dependency graph that causes it to build two separate images, which it does in parallel as you expect. If you `RUN` a different script or `COPY` some unique file(s) in each stage they will build in parallel. Even just setting a unique `ENV` is enough to trigger this.

Below is a very minimal test that demonstrates this behavior (using alpine as a base image which is only around 5.5MB) :

#### test.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
touch /test
```

#### Dockerfile A

```dockerfile
FROM alpine AS base
WORKDIR /run
COPY ./test.sh .

FROM base AS first
RUN /run/test.sh

FROM base AS second
RUN /run/test.sh

FROM base AS output
COPY --from=first /test .
COPY --from=second /test .
```

#### Command

```sh
sudo DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --no-cache .
```

#### Output

[image]

You can see that the `first` stage is skipped, and the `second` stage took just over `10` seconds to complete. Yet the `COPY` command in the `output` stage has no trouble reading from the `first` stage.

Now, if we add an `ENV` with a unique value in each stage...

#### Dockerfile B

```dockerfile
FROM alpine AS base
WORKDIR /run
COPY ./test.sh .

FROM base AS first
ENV test=A
RUN /run/test.sh

FROM base AS second
ENV test=B
RUN /run/test.sh

FROM base AS output
COPY --from=first /test .
COPY --from=second /test .
```

#### Both stages are built in parallel :

[image]